# android google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps

i have several markers on the google map displayed in android,  i wish to display more information (information such as - some text,a picture) when a particular marker is clicked. could some one please guide me how can i go about implementing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onTap()` in your `ItemizedOverlay` and do whatever you want. [See here for a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) that displays a `Toast` when an item is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

What CommonsWare said.
Or check out this page: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
Also, I would recommend launching a new Activity if you're going to display text and an image, unlike the application at the page where only a small text is displayed.

Comment: Just a note that Google Maps Android v1 has been deprecated. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview